# Difference between Flask abort() or returning a status

Tags: python, flask

What is the difference between `abort(400)` and returning a response with a 400 status? Is using return bad form for errors?

```
abort(400, "some error message")
# or
return {'message': "some error message"}, 400
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`abort` raises an error, which an error handler will convert to a response. `return` returns a response, error handlers don't trigger. It's up to how you want your application to flow.

Answer (score 9):

`abort` is a wrapper that raises `HTTPException` classes. Calling `abort` is the same as raising an exception and Flask will handle both the same way. Returning is not the same as raising an exception and will be handled differently.